# Recyclerview expand/collapse a number of items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have found many libraries supporting expand/collapse for every item in `recyclerview`. Is there any library that supports expanding and collapsing of `recyclerview` not for each item but for example:

1) Display top 3 items by default 
2) A button below recyclerview to expand the entire list / collapse back to top 3 items

I tried to find but couldn't find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be easy to do right within your adapter.

- Add a flag to your adapter class:

  ```
      private boolean mExpanded;
  ```
- Add a new method to call when the button is clicked:

  ```
      public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
          mExpanded = expanded;
          notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
  ```
- Then modify your `getItemCount` method something like this:

  ```
      @Override
      public int getItemCount() {
          return mExpanded ? itemlist.size() : 3;
      }
  ```

It doesn't matter that the rest of the items are still in the adapter list; if you tell the `RecyclerView` there are only three items, then that's all it will show.